# Upgrade the project from struts 1 to struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

When updating the current project to struts 1 to struts 2, what is the best approach to do it? 
For example i have below jars and some others,

struts-core-1.3.5
struts-el-1.3.5
struts-extras-1.3.5
struts-faces-1.3.5
etc

so when i upgrade to 2.x of same jars, how i know the current versions of dependency jars which above struts jars using because i need to upgrade them also with the struts jars know.
Is there a tool or a best approach to upgrade the struts and to find out the versions of the dependency jars when update?

Comment: How to find the jar dependencies? Use a dependency manager, like Maven or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You not only have to upgrade the libraries but also to migrate the whole application. See http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/migration-guide.html where you find some pointers how to start.

EDIT: There doesn't exist an official migration guide anymore, but you may found some help at https://www.infoq.com/news/migrating-struts2/

Comment: link got broken,please update with new link